# RavenDb index to filter&sort on properties of the nested structure/collection (fanout index)

Tags: c#, indexing, nosql, ravendb, ravendb4

I'm looking for a way to create a [static index](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/csharp/indexes/creating-and-deploying) to serve filtering/sorting queries for a combination of property values in the nested structure (a collection of objects) along with the structure-container. It seems to be not trivial due to the following reasons:

- If properties of the nested structure/collection are separated out into individual fields of the index (individual collections), then it makes impossible using the `AND` condition when filtering on 2+ properties of the nested structure/collection.
- The [fanout index](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/Csharp/indexes/fanout-indexes) complexity (see an [example](https://maggiepint.com/2015/08/16/ravendb-common-mistake-1-nested-list-indexes/)), which makes any solution to run too slow.

---

Given the following persistent model:

```
public class Document
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<UserChange> RecentModifications { get; set; }
}
```

where

```
public class UserChange
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

**Question:** How to build the index for `Document` to filter/sort by a combination of  all the fields: `Title`, `UserId` and `Timestamp`?

Possible use cases:

- get all documents containing the word 'contract' for a certain user and a date range
- sort documents containing the word 'contract' by last modification made by the user.

---

P.S. I understand that the indexing restrictions can by bypassed by restructuring the persistence model - storing a structure for recently modified documents in the `User` document, but it'd impose some other limitations, which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be solved by using [Indexes with Dynamic Fields](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/Csharp/indexes/using-dynamic-fields). It allows to keep logical data structure and avoids creating a [fanout index](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/csharp/indexes/fanout-indexes).

**Solution**

Create the following index for the `Document` collection from the above:

```
public class MyIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Document, DocumentIndDto>
{
    public MyIndex()
    {
        // Add fields that are used for filtering and sorting
        Map = docs =>
            from e in docs
            select new
            {
                Title = e.Title, 
                _ = e.RecentModifications.Select( x => CreateField ($"{nameof(Document.RecentModifications)}_{x.UserId}", x.Timestamp))
            };
    }
}

public class DocumentIndDto
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,DateTime> RecentModifications { get; set; }
}
```

Query on `MyIndex` like

```
var q = s.Query<DocumentIndDto, MyIndex>()
                .Where(p => p.Title == "Super" && p. RecentModifications["User1"] < DateTime.Now);
```

**Explanation**

The specified index with dynamic fields will generate extra fields and terms for each record in the following format:

```
RecentModifications_User1 = '2018-07-01';
RecentModifications_User2 = '2018-07-02';
```

The format is important, because when you use a dictionary in your high-level query like `myDic[key]`, it gets transformed to `myDic_key` in the generated RQL. Hence, it will allow us to use these fields in queries.

If you query with using the usual `Query` rather than `DocumentQuery` (see [docs](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/csharp/indexes/querying/query-vs-document-query)), then you need a proper data type for LINQ to work. For that purpose I created `DocumentIndDto` class, where my `RecentModifications` has become a dictionary, so I could use it in a high-level query and get correct RQL like

```
from index 'MyIndex' where Title = $p0 and RecentModifications_User1 = $p1
```

For more details, see my [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ravendb/YvPZFIn5GVg/907Msqv4CQAJ) on the subject with Oren Eini (aka Ayende Rahien).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following RQL in your index definition:

```
from doc in docs.Documents
from modification in doc.RecentModifications 
select new {
    modification.UserId,
    modification.Timestamp
}
```

**Note**: 'UserId' & 'timestamp' are NOT separated in the underlying index-entry.

So filtering on a combination UserId='A' AND Timestamp='2018-01-01' ***WILL*** return records modified by user 'A' on '2018-01-01'.

See also [Fanout Indexes](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/csharp/indexes/fanout-indexes)

**Note2**:
The 'Title' can also be indexed and searched on using:

```
from doc in docs.Documents
from modification in doc.RecentModifications 
select new {
    doc.Title,
    modification.UserId,
    modification.Timestamp
}
```

So each resulting 'index entry' will contain the *'UserId'* & *'Timestamp'* as before -and- the relevant *'Title'*

Comment: It's what I called flattening  the structure, because it creates a collection of all users and timestamps for the document. So filtering on a combination `UserId='A' AND Timestamp='2018-01-01'` won't return records modified by user 'A' on '2018-01-01'. It'll return all records, which were edited by user 'A' and the ones which were modified on '2018-01-01' (by any user). I'll add a bit of clarification in my original post.

Comment: No, not by 'any' user, by user 'A' only - see above note added to answer

Comment: Sorry @Danielle, I glossed over the key component of my question - the need to use fields from the structure-container along with the fields from the nested structure. I've updated the question in my post above.

Comment: See note2 above - fields from the structure-container can also be used (e.g. the Title field)